# Looking for a volume control valve for an under the sink water purifier

Tags: plumbing

Since I am into plumbing these days I would like to fix one problem that has been pestering us for quite a while now. I installed an under the sing water purifier ([**This Guy,**](https://www.lowes.ca/product/rainfresh-12-12-in-under-sink-complete-system-271745)  RainFresh SST Mode). The water is coming out way too fast, some times splashing over the counter if you fully open the tap (*it has its own tap*)

Is there any way to control the volume  for this thing ?(*I guess this is the problem*)  Opening the tap more or less seems to do the thing but you need to pay attention and the pressure is just to much and you can't always get it right so the water splashes all over the place.

Here is the diagram, the only difference in my case is that I have a shutoff valve on the 1/2" pipe and then right on top of it I have a 5/8x3/8x5/8 compression tee that branches out the 3/8 line for the water purifier and also goes to the regular cold water tap using a hose

So I guess I need something that can be either attached inline to the 3/8 pipe that feeds the purifier or replace the T with one that has a turn off valve on the 3/8 line, I just can't find the part

[image]

Comment: Flow control valves are quite common accessories for RO filter systems - they can be purchased separately and come in various rates. But really, this just sounds like a crappy "own faucet" and replacing that with one less "all or nothing" seems a more straightforward fix, but hard to tell until you try if a different one is going to be better that way.

Comment: Not sure if I want to buy and install a new filtered water faucet just to learn that it is no better than the existing one. I think that this is happening because practically the water pressure is too much for the diameter of the tap (see above the last picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 1/4 turn valve on the line to the filter and just  keep it partially closed.  You can use a push to connect valve.

**Bonus:** You can close that valve to change the filter without shutting down water to the other fixture.

[image]

Photo from [Mosquitomax.com](https://store.mosquitomax.com/3-8-shut-off-Valve-nickel-plated-brass-p/86320-06-06.htm)

Comment: I can't find anything like this only the compression models are available
Is it possible to attach a compression model directly to the compression tee that I have there (1/2x3/8X1/2 compression tee)

Comment: Does this fit the bill ? https://www.amazon.ca/uxcell-Connector-Connect-Fitting-Purifiers/dp/B08HZ55MRK

Comment: Yes that seems like it would work. there are several different versions of in-line quarter turn valves for 3/8  inch line. If you can find a metal one,  I think it would last longer but as long as you’re not using it on a regular basis the plastic won’t wear out.

Comment: Can't find a metal one in Canada :-(

Comment: I just found this one https://www.google.com/shopping/product/14428108839558319858?q=3/8%22+push+to+connect+straight+valve&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA910CA910&sxsrf=ALeKk03Fj_ZSBYxhVQ1gx7R63Mxa0QJ3Bg:1619227564733&biw=1536&bih=796&dpr=1.25&prds=eto:9673820651263615657_0&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_ipjBhpbwAhWaVs0KHWzACT04ZBDzAgiwEQ but I think it is 1/2" compression and I need 5/8" at one end since the hose it attached directly to the existing tee

Comment: I think I am going to give up on the push in requirement for this
https://www.lowes.ca/product/38-in-dia-chrome-compression-quarter-turn-straight-valve-586694